# Angular 13 Leaflet Will Not Render Map Correctly

Tags: leaflet, rendering, openstreetmap, angular13

I am having an issue where when I attempt to render a map using Leaflet in Angular 13, I am getting the following...

[image: Incorrectly Rendered Map]

I have the leaflet.css and styles.css loaded in the angular.json file...

```
"styles": ["src/styles.scss", 
           "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"]
```

I have the leaflet.css and styles.css loaded in the app.component.ts...

```
styleUrls: ['./on-site-proctor-locator.component.scss',
            '../../../../../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css']
```

In the app.component.ts file, here is where I initialize the map...

```
this.map = L.map('map').setView([ lat, lon ], zoom); 
const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 20,
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://stadiamaps.com/">Stadia Maps</a>, &copy; <a href="https://openmaptiles.org/">OpenMapTiles</a>' +
            '&copy; <a href="openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
});
tiles.addTo(this.map);
```

Here is what I have setup in the app.component.html file for the div...

```
<div id="map" class="map-div"></div>
```

I have looked at other posts of similar struggles and have found nothing that has helped me. I would appreciate any suggestions on what I can do to resolve this issue.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me (angular 14 project+leaflet 1.8):

on this line

```
<div id="map" class="map-div"></div>
```

add a width and height, to read something like this

```
<div id="map" class="map-div" style="width: 100%; height: 300px"></div>
```

leaflet requires the container to be visible, and have a reference width/height in order to render correctly.

I hope it helps